# java. Цикл for совершает по два прохода за раз

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
Никак не могу понять, почему при следующем коде фор по два прохода за раз делает, когда я ожидаю один проход?

```
    int i;
    System.out.println("Для остановки нажмите клавишу S");
    for (i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++) {
        System.out.println("Пpoxoд #" + i);
    }
```

Вывод:

```
Для остановки нажмите клавишу S
w
Пpoxoд #0
Пpoxoд #1
e
Пpoxoд #2
Пpoxoд #3
s
Пpoxoд #4
Пpoxoд #5
S
```

Comment: System.in.read() также запоминает символ переноса строки '\n', поэтому и получается 2 прохода (символ введенный и перенос строки)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!